# Mounting a Samba Share as a File

Tags: networking, samba, fstab, kubuntu

This issue has been driving me crazy after about three months of fussing with it. Here's the current situation.

I have an ntfs drive (left over from the windows days) on a computer running Kubuntu with samba. A specific folder on the drive is mounted as a samba share and access privilege is open to any for read, write, and execute. This share is easily accessed by all on the network by smb://location and through Dolphin's network interface as well.

The problem arises that office suites can't find the network (why isn't this an option???) to save to it. I've tried FreeOffice, Open Office, and LibreOffice, and the yes, I've tried LibreOffice's save remote but it doesn't work.

I've tried a ton of different ideas for mounting to fstab, including using auto and another command (the name escapes me for the moment) that allows a laptop to mount a share after the network has been established. This works one time. After another reboot, the file system will freeze for minutes on end and then the mount file in the user directory is empty and no longer accessible. The file/directory itself is not accessible. I can still access the samba share by going to smb://location but the fstab mount point breaks and causes the computer to freeze. It's highly frustrating because it works one time around, but then breaks. If I create a new directory and change the fstab mount point to that directory, it works again, and then breaks on reboot.

I want to be able to have the samba share auto mount as a file (directory) in the user's home directory on boot.

The reasoning: Office suite software cannot write to the smb:// drive and will instantly default to KDE's cache and cannot find the network files. We need to be able to not only open files from the network, but also create and save new ones. Thus, I need the network mounted as a file in the user's home directory to have access to the entire network. (Perhaps there's a different solution?)

Any help, direction, advice on how to solve this issue is greatly appreciated.

/etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=49a150dd-e4ed-4adf-85f0-dfb2fa985be6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=BE24-E7B8  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
//stan-lx/r /home/k/RN cifs _netdev,username=guest,password=,uid=1000,auto,iocharset=utf8,comment=systemd.automount, 0 0
```

Comment: Please post your `/etc/fstab`; add to your question.

Comment: Added /etc/fstab

Comment: Do you *really* need this share active on boot, or just when it's accessed? I would look into autofs - it will mount any share on demand, even shut it down when it's not being used.

Comment: Just when it's accessed. Thanks, I'll look into autofs.

Comment: I've got it up and working (autofs). Interestingly, this only works with an IP address and not with the server name. Any tips on resolving this?

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Comment: In the past, I've had to either use the IP address or add .local to the server name. But this was only on certain systems; not sure what the logic was, but it worked.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much. I've got a few other systems I need to get working on this same network, and so I'll give the .local a go as well. You would think there would be a little more standardization, but I've learned with networking, not too much is logical.